# Laravel Rate Limiting remembers X-Ratelimit-Remaining from other throttle-routes - leads to false too many requests

Tags: laravel

In my api.php I have my main routes grouped within:

```
Route::middleware('throttle:60,1')->group(function() { //all my main api routes});
```

However, I have routes, that need custom times. For example, if the user needs to type his/her password again when he/she changes something in the settings.

```
//outside of the throttle:60,1
Route::post('/password/check', 'Api\CheckPasswordController@check')
     ->middleware('throttle:3,1', 'auth:api');
```

**My goal** is that the user can only type his/her password 3 times, after that he/she needs to cool down.

However, I noticed that when I fetch URLs from the API the "X-Ratelimit-Remaining" is already used up. This leads to the problem that the user needs to cooldown when the password was typed in.

I wrote a PHPUnit test to prove that there is a bug:

```
/** @test */
public function throttle_works_correctly_even_when_other_api_url_are_called()
{
    $this->withExceptionHandling();

    $this->otherApiUrl()->assertStatus(200);

    $this->url(['currentPassword' => 'secret'])->assertStatus(200);

    $this->url(['currentPassword' => 'secret'])->assertStatus(200);

    $this->url(['currentPassword' => 'secret'])->assertStatus(200); <-- fails at this part

    $this->url(['currentPassword' => 'secret'])
        ->assertStatus(429);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is no way because throttling works like that. However, I found another solution. Just copy [ThrottlesLogin](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php) and adjust to your needs. Works fine like that :)